# Agregar un dato del tipo List<> a una base de datos SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-management

Estoy con un proyecto para la facultad, el cual incluye SQL.
Tengo una entidad llamada *Venta*, y dentro de esta hay un atributo del tipo `List`, el cual contiene objetos de tipo *Producto*, el cual es otra entidad del proyecto.

Actualmente tengo los datos de estas ventas en un .XML pero quería hacerlo en una base de datos. El problema es que no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, ya que eso requeriría un tipo de dato de lista para la columna correspondiente. Cómo podría solucionarlo?
Adjunto imágenes de las entidades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(*Producto* es clase padre y la utilizo para otras tres entidades)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consideré utilizar el tipo de dato XML, pero no comprendí cómo funcionaba.

Comment: Y si normalizas la cosa y guardas un registro por cada elemento de la lista? Eso hará más barato operar sobre la lista y buscar. También es más barato transferir resultados de una búsqueda... guardar el XML sería unar una BD para guardar un archivo que debió ser una BD, y eso es un desperdicio

Comment: averigua q es entityframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas una tabla nueva que relacione la tabla **Productos** con la tabla **Venta**. Por eso se llaman **Bases de datos relacionales**. Esta nueva tabla debería tener *Foreign Keys* hacia esas dos tablas. Tendrías que hacer varios *inserts* manualmente para almacenar los datos, a menos que estés usando **Entity Framework.**

Por ejemplo:

```
  Id_Venta       Id_Producto
     1               3
     1               7
     1               8
     2               4
     2               6
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder. Te consulto, esta nueva tabla, qué datos tendría? La idea sería guardar en cada "Venta" varios productos, cada uno con sus propios atributos.

Comment: @MarcosLaporte La tabla venta necesita un Id único, por lo tanto la tabla que las relaciona tendría `Id_Venta` y `Id_Producto`

Comment: Pero cómo hago si son varios productos en una misma venta? La tabla `producto` es para guardar el "stock" por así decir.